# Direction Variation Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The variable $x$ varies directly as the cube of $y$, and $y$ varies directly as the square root of $z$. If $x$ equals 1 when $z$ equals 4, what is the value of $z$ when $x$ equals 27?

All I know is $x=ky^3, y=k\sqrt{z}$, ($k$ being the constant) and I don't even know if this is correct. I was wondering if any one could help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

So indeed, you are given that $x = ay^3$ and $y = b\sqrt{z}$, which implies $x = a \left(b\sqrt{z}\right)^3 = ab^3 z^{3/2}$.

Now you are given then $z=4 \implies x=1$.

- Find $ab^3$ with direct substitution
- Now plug in both $ab^3$ and $x=27$, can you find $z$?